# Multiple forms on one page, get input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML for this page is the following:

```
<div class="list-block media-list">
    <ul>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <li >
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media">
                        <img  width="80">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title-row">
                            <div class="item-title">Element title</div>
                            <div class="item-after">Unexcused</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-subtitle">Subtitle</div>
                        <div class="item-text">Additional description text</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="client_id" id="client_id" value="23" />
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <li class="red">
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media">
                        <img width="80">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title-row">
                            <div class="item-title">Element title</div>
                            <div class="item-after">Excused</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-subtitle">Subtitle</div>
                        <div class="item-text">Additional description text</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="client_id" id="client_id" value="27" />
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.media-list li').on('click', function () {
        var buttonValue = $(this).closest('#client_id').prop("value");
        alert(buttonValue);
    });
});
```

When I click on the `<li>` it is supposed to alert the `client_id` value, which it does, but it is always `23`, which is the correct number if I were to click the first `<li>`. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: HTML id should be unique

Comment: **And** `.closest()` does do what you want it to do :( `$('.child').closest('.parent')` return the first ancestor of `.child` that matches the selector `.parent`, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs should be unique, you can use attribute value selector here. also use `.val()` to get the values for input types:

```
$(this).closest('form').find("[name=client_id]").val();
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! I will mark yours as the answer in about 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `id should be unique`. In your case, you can get the parent form and find the id with in it.  Also follow standard template like `<ul><li>template</li></ul>`

Just try

```
$(this).parents('form:first').find('#client_id').val()
```

Comment: `closest` is preferable to using `parents` with a `first` filter (more readable too). :)

Answer (score 0):

You should never duplicate ids; that leads to HTML that's not valid. Use a css class instead or use `name` to select the `hidden` form element:

```
 $(this).closest('form').find('input[name=client_id]').val();
```

Or with your HTML changed to:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="status" class="status" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="client_id" class="client_id" value="27" />
```

Your JS would be:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('.client_id').val();
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to duplicate ids, it was doing only alerting the same one.

Comment: Yes, because `$(this).closest('#client_id')` does not do what you think it is doing: see my comment in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't the best choice for such a basic code.

But if you absolutely need jQuery, you can do like this:

```js
$(this).parent().find('[name=client_id]').val();
```

But, if you aren't worried about jQuery and if you care about performance, you can use this:

```js
(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]||{value:undefined}).value;
```

The latest won't work if the order changes.

Or you can try (untested and shorter than the jQuery solutions):

```js
this.parentNode.elements.client_id.value;
```

Doc: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml